# Can't check in changes to TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I am having issues trying to check in changes to TFS hosted on Visual Studio Online. Started just last week. I am running `Visual Studio Professional 2017` version `15.5.2`.

When I try to check in changes, I get this error:

`C:\My\Workspace\Path\Project\File.cs: Download of item $/Workspace/Path/Project/file.cs was not completed. Perform a get operation to correct.`
[image]

Okay, whatever. Sounds simple enough.
So I go to the problem file and do a `Get Latest Version`. 
When I do that, I then get this error:

```
Source Control Explorer  
The network path was not found.
```

[image]

The output in the `Output` window after attempting the get is this:

```
Conflict C:\...\...\...\...\...\Program.cs - Unable to perform the get operation because you have a conflicting edit
Automatically resolved conflict: edit: C:\...\...\...\...\...\Program.cs as TakeTheirs
The network path was not found.
```

I have read a number of posts, and tried a number of things. None have fixed the issue. Things I have tried...

- Delete the TFS cached under AppData. Did nothing to help.
- Disconnect VS from the TFS project, then delete the hidden `$tf` folder under my local workspace and then reconnect VS to the team project and re-get everything. The initial re-gets all worked. But once I made some changes to a project and then tried to check it in, it started with these errors again.

Anyone have any other ideas? The next step I see in my future is having to uninstall and reinstall visual studio, but I'm REALLY trying to avoid that.

Comment: Did you delete and recreate the workspace? It looks like the workspace is messed up.

Comment: @DanielMann Hmm... have not tried that. I will give that a try and report back.

Comment: Try: Get Specific version, specify a Changeset number from a few days back. Then perform a Get Latest.

Comment: @jessehouwing Thanks for the suggestion. Just tried that. I picked an older version to get.  It told me there was a non-vc copy of the file on disc and asked me if I wanted to overwrite it. I said yes, and then it gave me the same "network path not found" error. Guess it's on to trying to delete the whole workspace and recreate it like daniel suggested. *sigh*

Comment: Your Virus Scanner may also be causing issues....

Comment: @DanielMann - Thanks! Deleting and recreating the workspace seems to have fixed it. If you post that as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. Awesome!

Comment: @DanielMann - plus side, it seems to also have made all TFS operations MUCH faster! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the solution is Deleteing and recreating the workspace.

You will meet similar issues when a workspace is messed up.

Generally, you can try below item to fix such an issue:

- Disconnect any instance, close VS, then delete the **cache** folder located at: e.g. `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache`, then restart the VS, connect to TFS/VSTS again.
- Remap the workspace to a new folder
- Delete the old workspace and create a new one, map it.

Answer (score 0):

By the by, ... I had this issue again today, and had a slightly different fix. When I went to delete my workspace, I found that a prior aborted new project had somehow added additional working folder mappings to my workspace. So I deleted those, after which VS said it needed to restart. So I let it, and now everything seems to be working fine.

Just figured I'd let people know, in case they find that situation, so they needn't go through with the whole other drastic measures, to check this first and try it if it applies.