# "The network path was not found" when trying to view Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

We are using TFS 2018 and Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.17).  Everything worked fine for a few months after initial set-up, but now when I try to view Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio, I get the error message "The network path was not found".  I **can** open solutions in Visual Studio from TFS, however, so I know the network path is working.  But then, when I try to check items in, the network path error occurs again.

Googling does not turn up any solutions to this issue so far.  Any ideas on what to try next?  Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a workspace mapped to a network share?

Comment: No, the only workspace I have is on my local PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed!  The answer was found here:  [Can't check in changes to TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48012831/cant-check-in-changes-to-tfs)

Short answer was a corrupt workspace.  Removing the workspace and re-creating it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache on your computer and check whether the issue persists:

1. Close Visual Studio.
2. Browse to the following folder: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache.
3. Delete the contents of the Cache directory, including all subfolders.

Comment: Clearing the cache as described above did not resolve the issue.